# RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField (unbound) received a naive datetime , when increment duration until datetime.now

Tags: django, datetime, duration

I'm trying to increment a duration until a condition. Data is saved in database but page doesn't refresh and I'm getting this error. What can be done?

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField (unbound) received a naive datetime (2021-07-04 18:54:38.827527) while time zone support is active. warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)"
```

I'm using this code in my views

```
    from datetime import datetime
...
 if form.is_valid():
        numof=form.cleaned_data['Numero_Of']
        QuerySet_of=OF.objects.get(Numero_Of=numof)
        Usin=Poste.objects.get(OF_id=QuerySet_of.Id_OF,Nom_poste__startswith = "MGP")
        while Usin.Date_S_poste is None :
            OF.objects.filter(Id_OF=QuerySet_of.Id_OF).update(Nb_jrs_att_Usin = datetime.now() - F('Date_E_initial'))
```

models.py

```
    Nb_jrs_att_Usin=models.DurationField(null=True, blank=True)
```

In my settings, I have changed TIME_ZONE to

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Tunis'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = False  
USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: That is only warning! Instead of `from datetime import datetime` use `from django.utils import timezone` and then `Nb_jrs_att_Usin=timezone.now() - ...`

Comment: There is another reason why the page is not refreshing. Show your full view.